# counterexample to "symmetric" nine lemma

Tags: homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Consider a commutative diagram of $R$-modules

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
@. 0 @. 0 @. 0\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
0@>>>A_1@>a>>A_2@>a'>>A_3@>>>0\\
@. @VVfV@VVgV @VVhV\\
0@>>>B_1@>b>>B_2@>b'>>B_3@>>>0\\
@. @VVf'V @VVg'V @VVh'V\\
0@>>>C_1@>c>>C_2@>c'>>C_3@>>>0\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
@. 0 @. 0 @. 0\\
\end{CD}$$

such that the three rows and the first and third columns are short exact sequences.

I am looking for a counterexample to the claim that the middle column is exact.

I know it to be true that if $\text{Im } g \subset \ker g',$ then the middle column is in fact exact.

I was able to show via diagram chase that if $C_1$ is $0$, then the middle column is exact.

Comment: If you want better looking commutative diagrams, use [AMScd](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram).

Comment: AMScd is not so good. It can't draw diagonal arrows. The best modern solutions are `tikz-cd` and _the `psmatrix` environment from `pst-node`.

Comment: I am always confused when s.e.s. are written $A\to B\to C$ insetad of $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
0@>>>R@>1>>R\\
@VVV@VV\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}V @VV1V\\
R@>\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}>>R^2@>\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\end{pmatrix}>>R\\
@VV1V @VV\begin{pmatrix}1&0\end{pmatrix}V @VVV\\
R@>1>>R@>>>0\\
\end{CD}$$